# How do I tell a native node.js extension where to find (the right) libstdc++?

Tags: node.js, path, native, libstdc++, node-gyp

I’m installing `scrypt` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrypt) from npm. The installation involves a `node-gyp` build step that builds a native node.js extension. When I then start my app, it fails with the following error:

```
node index.js 
module.js:568
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: /package/host/localhost/gcc-4/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/xxxx/xxxx/node_modules/scrypt/build/Release/scrypt.node)
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:568:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xxxx/xxxx/node_modules/scrypt/index.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xxxx/xxxx/node_modules/unfun-cms/lib/utils/password.js:3:16)
```

which is not so surprising, because

```
[xxxx@xxxx nodeapp]$ strings /package/host/localhost/gcc-4/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep "GLIBCXX_3\.4\.21"
[xxxx@xxxx nodeapp]$
```

while

```
[xxxx@xxxx nodeapp]$ strings /package/host/localhost/gcc-5/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep "GLIBCXX_3\.4\.21"
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
[xxxx@xxxx nodeapp]$
```

I have

```
export PATH=/package/host/localhost/gcc-5/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/package/host/localhost/gcc-5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

in my `.bashrc`, and `gcc --version` shows `5.2.0` correctly, so I assume these settings are alright.

So the question is, how do I tell `scrypt` the path to the correct `libstdc++.so.6`, namely the one at `/package/host/localhost/gcc-5/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`? (And why does it even get it wrong?)

EDIT:

This is a CentOS machine. I’m using node.js version `6.1.0`, npm version `3.8.6`, and I’m trying to install `scrypt` version `6.0.3`, which is the latest version at the time of this writing.

EDIT 2:

I tried to statically link the library by editing `node_modules/scrypt/binding.gyp`, adding

```
'libraries': ['/package/host/localhost/gcc-5/lib64/libstdc++.so.6'],
```

to each of the four specified targets, and then running `node-gyp rebuild`.

I also tried changing this to

```
'libraries': ['-L/package/host/localhost/gcc-5/lib64', '-lstdc++'],
```

, which appears to be syntactically valid, too—but still, it tries to load the library from the wrong path at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I stubled with a similar trouble and had resolve it with a trick uses dynamic load of libstdc++.so.6 through LD_PRELOAD:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/path/to/lib/libstdc++.so.6' /usr/bin/nodejs app.js
```