# Linking native node.js extansion with c++17 supporting libstd

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, c++17, node-gyp

I'm trying to use my native node.js addon on linux machine after building it.
And I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /root/addon/node_modules/addon/build/Release/addonstrong text.node)
```

After some investigation - i understand i need to link at compilation of the addon the proper libstdc++ lib (seems to be libstdc++.so.6).
But the used flags doesn't seem to do any good - this is a part of the binding.gyp used:

```
'cflags!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
'cflags_cc!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
'conditions': [
              ["OS=='linux'", {
                   'cflags_cc': [
                                '-lstdc++ -std=c++17'
                                ],
                    'link_settings': {
                                 'ldflags': [
                                          '-R,<(module_root_dir)/lib/linux/libstdc++.so.6'
                                                ],
                     'libaries':   ['<(module_root_dir)/lib/linux/libstdc++.so.6'
     ],
    }
}]
```

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392348/how-do-i-tell-a-native-node-js-extension-where-to-find-the-right-libstdc) - but they solve it with changing enviroment variable instead of linking it during compilation.